# XML validation against XSD that includes more XSDs: type is not declared

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a problem in validating XML against XSD when the base XSD is importing some other XSDs from site. For example, for the following XSD item, it is throwing error.

```
<link:linkbase xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:link = 'http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase' xmlns:xbrli = 'http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance' xmlns:xlink = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xsi:schemaLocation = 'http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd' >
```

Is there any solution for importing the XSD by release version of DLLs. I am using the following C# code for validating XML against the XSD. The same is working when I execute it through Visual Studio.

```
var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(null, xsdFilePath);

var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
readerSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
readerSettings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
readerSettings.Schemas.Add(schemas);

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, readerSettings))
{
    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
    }  
}
```

Comment: Provide error message.

Comment: "Type 'http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance:stringItemType' is not declared." This is the error throwing because it is defined in the followng schema. <xs:import namespace='http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance' schemaLocation='http://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd'/>. If i rpovide a physical file instead of URL, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the parser cannot find the schema `xbrl-instance-2003-12-31`. From the [w3 schema specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#schema-loc):

> (`xsi:schemaLocation`) records the author's warrant with pairs of URI references (one for the namespace name, and one for a hint as to the location of a schema document defining names for that namespace name)

that is, the first part of your schemaLocation definition `xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd` **is the namespace**. If the parser doesn't already know where to find the schema for such namespace, **you must provide it with the location**. For example:

```xml
<xs:import
    namespace='xbrl.org/2003/instance'
    schemaLocation='xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd http:/xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd'/>
```